# How to Destroy GameObjects from PrefabInstallers after Installation?

Tags: zenject

I might have misunderstood the PrefabInstaller but I want to use it to let the LevelDesigner configure settings. However, Zenject seems not to destroy the PrefabInstallers afert installation and so I am left over with unecessary Installer-GameObjects (xyzInstaller (Clone)). How do I properly clean them up?

Comment: Have you considered using ScriptableObjectInstaller instead?  If you do that, then new objects won't be added to the scene and also has the advantage that you can configure settings on it at runtime and have those settings persist

Comment: @Steve Vermeulen, Thank you! I am very happy that you give so much support for Zenject, it is really an amazing library. I have no experience with the scriptable object installer yet but I will look into it!